# Is there a way to sort an array in a random order

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to sort a JavaScript array in a random order kind of like this:

```
var string1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var string2 = [
string1[math.floor(math.random() * 6)],
string1[math.floor(math.random() * 6)],
string1[math.floor(math.random() * 6)],
string1[math.floor(math.random() * 6)],
string1[math.floor(math.random() * 6)],
string1[math.floor(math.random() * 6)],
string1[math.floor(math.random() * 6)],
string1[math.floor(math.random() * 6)],
string1[math.floor(math.random() * 6)],
string1[math.floor(math.random() * 6)]
];

document.write(
string2[0] + 
string2[1] + 
string2[2] +
string2[3] +
string2[4] +
string2[5] +
string2[6] +
string2[7] +
string2[8] +
string2[9] );
```

Is there any way to do that but without any numbers repeating or doing an if/else statement for each possible combination saying if they are equal change it?

Comment: An array of numbers is not really a string.

Comment: you mean string or array?

Comment: Look for Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: Just generate the array of subsequent numbers and then shuffle it: [How can i shuffle an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: array sorry i forgot